# C pthread.h not working

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am using gcc 4.6.3, and I am trying to write a program that uses asynchronous flow via threads. After some research, I decided that `threads.h` was best for windows and `pthread.h` was best for POSIX systems. So I used `pthread.h`.

After a lot of debugging, I have my code.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *exe(){
  char i;
  for(i = 0; i < 0; i++){
    printf("%c\n", i);
  }
}

int main(){
  long unsigned int *id = (void *)1ul;
  int d = pthread_create(id, NULL, exe, NULL);
}
```

> This code is not intended to be of any use, it is for me to teach myself threading.

The problem is that it throws the error

```
exit status 1
/file/path.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that the `pthread_create` function is undefined, but I have included the library and it didn't give me any directory not found errors.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Isnt it -lpthread?

Comment: It is, ya got me before I changed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Compile and **link** with

```
gcc -pthread main.c
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't try that out for myself, because I'm using an online compiler that doesn't allow custom build options. But I'll give you a vote anyway, thanks!

Comment: See the suggested duplicate why this answer likely won't work.